# MATLAB: How to Retrieve Intensity-Based Registration Data (with imregister) to re-Perform Registration?

Tags: matlab

I thought this should be a simple task, I just can't find the way to do it:

I am using 'imregister' (MATLAB) to register two medical X-ray images.
To ensure I get the best registration outcome as possible, I use some image processing techniques such as contrast enhancement, blackening of objects that are different between images and even cropping.
The outcome of this seems to be quite satisfying.

Now, I want to perform the exact same registaration on the original images, so that I can display the two ORIGINAL images automatically in alignment.

I think that an output parameter such as tform serves this purpose of performing a certain registration on any two images, but unfortunately 'imregister' does not provide such a parameter, as far as I know.

It does provide as an output the spatial referencing object R_reg which might be the answer, but I still haven't figured out how to use it to re-preform the registration.

I should mention that since I am dealing with medical X-ray images on which non of the feature-detecting algorithms seem to work well enough to perform registration, I can only use intensity-based (as opposed to feature-based) registration, and therefore am using 'imregister'.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Thanks!
Noga

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using? Since a couple releases (since R2013b I believe) there is [imregtform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imregtform.html) that you can use for that purpose along with `imwarp`. Or you can edit the code for `imregister` and force the `tform` to be an output. Actually `imregister` calls `imregtform` on the 1st line and `imwarp` in the last haha

Answer (score 3):

So to make an answer out of my comment, there are 2 things you can do depending on the Matlab release you are using:

**Option 1: R2013a and earlier**

I suggest modifying the built-in `imregister` function by forcing `tform` to be an output and save that function under another name.

For example:

```
function [movingReg,Rreg,tform] = imregister2(varargin)
```

save that, add it to your path and you're good to go. If you type `edit imregister` you will notice that the 1st line calls [imregtform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imregtform.html) to get the geometric transformation required, while the last line calls [imwarp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imwarp.html), to apply that geometric transformation. Which leads us to Option 2.

**Option 2: R2013b and later**

Well in that case you can directly use `imregtform` to get the tform object and then use `imwarp`to apply it. Easy isn't it?

Hope that makes things clearer!

Comment: I didn't realize that imregister calls imgetform... I assumed it had its own "intensity-based" algorithm. Thank you :)

Comment: you're welcome! If that helped could you mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the green tick mark below it? Thanks!